# How to get the number of Content Manager connections

Tags: content-manager

Other than executing a `netstat` command against the web server, does anyone know how to get the number of users connected to a content manager server UI? We are using "Domain" as the directory type.

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1190030.aspx?View+Active+Sessions+Connections

Comment: For a stateless web application like Tridion, "the number of users connected" is a bit of an odd thing to want to know. It would help, and give your question a Tridion context" if you explained what problem you are trying to solve.